# What does it mean by "random variables with values in $(E, \mathcal{E})$"?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process

I'm reading a note about optimal stopping in a Markovian setting

[image]

The author said that "a sequence $\left(X_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of random variables with values in $\color{blue}{(E, \mathcal{E})}$". It seems to me that he meant a sequence $\left(X_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of random variables with values in $\color{blue}{E}$, i.e., $$X_n: \Omega \to E$$

Could you verify if my understanding is correct?

Comment: Probably it means: values in $E$, measurable with respect to $\mathcal E$.

Comment: Thank you @GEdgar! Please write your comment as an answer so that I can accept it and close this question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it means: values in $E$, measurable with respect to $\mathcal E$.

In  order to be called a random variable, $f$ is supposed to be measurable.  But unless the range set has an understood-algebra, it must be specified.  In case the s et is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, we automatically use the Borel sets.